# Почему cpp округляет double?

Tags: c++, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Выполняю следующий код, в `num4` получаю `100.3`

```cpp
int main()
{
        double num1 = 100.10;
        double num2 = 0.002;
        double num3 = num1 * num2;

        double num4 = num1 + num3; //100.3
        return 0;
}
```

хотя если считать на калькуляторе, получается `100.3002`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в C++ получить такой же результат как на калькуляторе?

Пробовал функцию `round` из библиотеки `cmath`, все тщетно.

Comment: Чтобы получать результат, как на калькуляторе, следует вместо чисел с плавающей точкой использовать числа с фиксированной точкой или двоично-десятичные.

Comment: @user7860670 да ну, неужели у double такая низкая точность, что он не держит даже 7 знаков? // спойлер, дело в чем-то еще.

Comment: Вероятно, дело в том, КАК вы смотрите на значение. Уточните, где вы видите `100,3` в среде разработке, в принте, в отладчике, в выводе? Добавьте этот код или скриншот.

Comment: @Kromster На самом деле точность у double даже еще ниже, чем это. Уже в самом начале `100.10` внезапно превращается в `100.09...`

Comment: @user7860670 вообще-то, double precision type has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of **at least 15 digits**. А вот если вы его неправильно обрезаете-округляете - тогда конечно, проблема в этом.

Comment: @Kromster "вы его неправильно держите" ©, ага. Собственно double в принципе не могут представлять многие десятичные числа, например упомянутое 100.1, так что какое количество значащих разрядов потом остается после вычислений - совсем не важно.

Comment: Вероятнее всего автор вопроса использовал для вывода std::cout. Вот если бы он использовал printf, то ответ был бы верным. Поэтому здесь вопрос не в точности представления числа типа double, а в использовании различных средств вывода и их особенностях.